# Having trouble converting an audio signal to be usable by a mic input

Tags: audio, speakers, sound

So to start, to say that I'm a little out of my depth would be an understatement.

I have a single channel audio signal coming from a building intercom system ([data sheet](http://www.intercomsrus.com/handset%20pdf/Videx%203021%20_ac%20call_%20Door%20Entry%20Handset%20Data%20Sheet.pdf)). This audio signal is connected to a handset inside which has a speaker inside marker "45Ohm 0.25W".

When I connect this to a computer mic input, all I could hear was a loud buzzing noise so I checked the signal with a multimeter and found that it was about 11.4 volts. So, I made a simple voltage divider circuit (R1=10k Ohms, R2=220Ohms) to bring this down to about 0.25 volts. I connected the resultant signal to my computer and still the only thing I can hear is loud buzzing.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Probably need a bandpass filter. Might be why you're hearing a loud buzzing noise.

Comment: Well connecting something like that to a computer input is a bit scary. Personally I'd use an audio transformer to give yourself some isolation and you may still need to attenuate it, as you did. Try not to blow up either end though.

Comment: Some additional observations: connecting it to a laptop with a line in mode works, the sound is audible and clear. Connecting it to a mic input in parallel with the handset speaker also works. However, both of these solutions aren't very practical for me. @Trevor in retrospect I should have been more careful, but the equipment that I'm using has a total value of about £20 so I wasn't too concerned.

Comment: The mic input expects a very small signal. You are probably swamping the pre-amp.